# Pixi JS fromImage incredible slow on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, wamp, pixi.js

I'm using an example from pixi.js, its pretty basic but I have a problem while loading the 'bunny.png'. 
This is the example I'm using: http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/1/

On my computer using wamp, the bunny.png takes a whopping 13 seconds and sometimes even more, to load...

[image: chome devtools network loading]

It actually works a bit better on Firefox. The load time on firefox is nearly instant, even when refreshing with ctrl+F5.

The online version works on both browsers for me.

Anyone ever had this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was an extension called 'Hola'. For some weird reason that extension ruined my Apache. Removing that extension fixed my problem.